# PMD xpath tutorials

Tags: xpath, pmd, static-code-analysis

I'm about to write custom rules for my Java EE codebase,
Can anyone help where to begin for writing xpath rules? 
Is there any complete tutorial available for this?

Comment: If you need help with `XPATH` itself, I've found looking at the [tag:xpath] questions and answers here on SO to be very educational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) has a pretty good tutorials/examples.

Comment: w3schools just terrible. it became better over the last 1 or 2 years, but is still full of wrong and outdated information. please don't recommend such a bad site. for more information, please take a look at http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @oezi Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Even so, the XPath examples there are still helpful and accurate, and where I learned several ways of performing the searches.